# Programming addressable LED

Tags: arduino-uno, led, rgb-led

I have `TM1812` addressable `LED` strip (1meter long 96 LED). I am looking a way to `program` it and i found this http://www.deskontrol.net/blog/arduino-based-artnet-node-for-led-pixels/
and its mentioned in article that it doens't work with `current version` of Arduino `IDE`.

Is there some other lib/api available to program it or another method?

**UPDATE**
As mentioned by @dlu FastLED support wide variety of `LEDs`. I contacted developers of `FastLED` on google + and they have updated there documentation for support of `TM1812` its similar to `TM1809`

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice library called [FastLED](http://fastled.io), it is also on [GitHub as FastLED/FastLED](https://github.com/fastled/fastled). It is quite flexible and supports a huge range of addressable LEDs. I'm currently using it with 1.6.6.

The code that you linked to was developed with an older version of the Arduino IDE, so you might want to see if you can find an older version and try building with that.

Comment: I checked there reference sheet. its not mentioned anywhere they support TM1812. https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Chipset-reference

Comment: Ack, I'm sorry I was writing from memory and TM1812 is close to the WS2812 that the NeoPixel uses. I'll fix it…

Comment: Can i use `WS812` library to program `TM1812` or any other libs?

Comment: I need to go look at them. Do you have a data sheet you could link to? Looking at the GitHub page (https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Overview) I see that they are planning to support the TM1812, but don't have support yet. It might be worth contacting the authors and asking about the status of TM1812 support. Also since they support similar chips (by number) it would be worth comparing the data sheets to see how hard it would be support the newer chips.

Comment: How can i program them without using any library.

Answer (score -1):

All TM chip Family is supported by Fastled Libs if you use a TM1811 just put TM1809.

It should work, I have tried and it succeeded.